# Is php pagination compulsory?

Tags: php, pagination

sorry if the question seems too  idiot. I am student in development. I created a complete php website for posting stitches (with image video and audio) and then retrieving other users opinions on posted stitches. I made mobile ready and all. But I forgot to set pagination while building it. Yes that was not smart at all. Somehow I still don't have any issue with the website cause there are only 20-30 entries in the database. But in the future if I get more entries, will it freeze browsers considering the fact that there is no pagination for limiting query fetching. I'd like you to tell me what will technically happen if I don't set a pagination system.
If it is compulsory to set a pagination system, can you point me a very great and simple pagination tutorial !? 
Thank you

EDIT: Ok, thank you for answers, I will set a pagination system for better user experience. Once again, thanks to all of you !!!

RE-EDIT:
I did it !!!!!!! I used Ajax. Added a load more button button and refreshes div via Ajax. Merci !!

Comment: I doubt it'll "freeze" a browser. However, if you have a lot of images and some are high res., then that will take more time to load. Mobile users may not like that. I'd set a pagination method ASAP.

Comment: *"can you point me a very great and simple pagination tutorial !?"* - Just Google it, you'll find many and make sure you use one with a prepared statement.

Comment: For questions purely about producing the best User Experience (to paginate or not to paginate) you might try http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination plays a very important role in performance and user experience. As you are hitting to database and fetching more rows uses more memory which can slow database. On the other hand browsers can crash with a lot-of records. specially when you are making web services for mobile devices. So it is good practice to use pagination in php to avoid such overhauls of browser and database or any mobile device etc.